# Window is not defined while using mixitup in Nextjs

Tags: reactjs, next.js, mixitup

I'm using mixitup plugin in my Nextjs app and as soon as i import the plugin in my index page it will return this error:

"ReferenceError: window is not defined"

Here is my code:

```
import mixitup from 'mixitup';

export default function Home() {
  return <div>Hi</div>;
}
```

How should i solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `next/dynamic` with ssr disabled.

> To dynamically load a component on the client side, you can use the ssr option to disable server-rendering. This is useful if an external dependency or component relies on browser APIs like window.

from NextJs: [Dynamic Import with no SSR](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/dynamic-import#with-no-ssr)

```
import dynamic from "next/dynamic";

const mixitup = dynamic(() => import("mixitup"), {
  ssr: false,
});
```

Comment: `mixitup` library is not a React component. Dynamically importing this way with `next/dynamic` won't work.

Comment: Well, it is not necessary to have it as a react component. See the integration of the pure mixitup npm package in a shortly created react app here: https://codesandbox.io/s/wonderful-browser-lil5bj?file=/src/App.js

Comment: I know, but that wasn't my point. `next/dynamic` can only be used with React components, which `mixitup` is not.

Comment: Thanks, didn't think about it enough. You are right.

Comment: @grenzbotin I used your code but it tells me mixitup is not a function